# MySQL stored procedure does not behave as expected?

Tags: mysql

I have faced a issue when I create a procedure in MySQL it works well.
after some days procedure not working as expected.

When execute procedure sometimes it return data exists for new value.
but when we checked `select * from test1 where fileid="""new value"" ;` data were not exists in the table.

If MySQL routine procedure  have any kind of cache to clear. Please suggest.

Test case:

```sql
CREATE  PROCEDURE `test_proc`(IN _FileID int)
sp_Exit: BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SHOW ERRORS;  
        ROLLBACK;
        select "some thing went wron with procedure";
        RESIGNAL;
    END;
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    IF EXISTS(select * from test1 where FileID=_FileID ) THEN
        select "data exists";
        LEAVE sp_Exit;
    END IF;
    START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO test1(FileID ) values (_FileID);
    COMMIT;   
END sp_Exit
```

Comment: I do not see the reason for described issue.

Comment: What is the reason to use `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`? If you have not decreased `sql_select_limit` dramatically than it makes no sense.

Comment: During formatting your SQL I found that last INSERT is not finalized with `;` - is it a typo?

Comment: Quite complicated way to simulate a unique index on the file id field...